# implementing a read/write field for an interface that only defines read

Tags: c#, c#-2.0, compiler-errors, field

I have a C# 2.0 application where a base interface allows read-only access to a value in a concrete class. But, within the concrete class, I'd like to have read/write access to that value. So, I have an implementation like this:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract DateTime StartTime { get; }
}

public class Foo : Base
{
    DateTime start_time_;

    public override DateTime StartTime
    {
        get { return start_time_; }
        internal set { start_time_ = value; }
    }
}
```

But, this gives me the error:

```
Foo.cs(200,22): error CS0546: 'Foo.StartTime.set': cannot override because 'Base.StartTime' does not have an overridable set accessor
```

I don't want the base class to have write access. But, I do want the concrete class to provide read/write access. Is there a way to make this work?

Thanks,
PaulH

---

Unfortunately, `Base` can't be changed to an interface as it contains non-abstract functionality also. Something I should have thought to put in the original problem description.

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract DateTime StartTime { get; }

    public void Buzz()
    {
        // do something interesting...
    }
}
```

My solution is to do this:

```
public class Foo : Base
{
    DateTime start_time_;

    public override DateTime StartTime
    {
        get { return start_time_; }
    }

    internal void SetStartTime
    {
        start_time_ = value;
    }
}
```

It's not as nice as I'd like, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to do this:

```
public class Foo : Base
{
    DateTime start_time_;

    public override DateTime StartTime
    {
        get { return start_time_; }
    }

    internal void SetStartTime
    {
        start_time_ = value;
    }
}
```

It's not as nice as I'd like, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

Any reason to not use an interface over the abstract class?

```
    public interface Base
    {
        DateTime StartTime { get; }
    }

    public class Foo : Base
    {
        DateTime start_time_;

        public DateTime StartTime
        {
            get { return start_time_; }
            internal set { start_time_ = value; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because an interface is not a substitute for an abstract base class :/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract DateTime StartTime { get; internal set; }
}
public class Foo : Base
{
    DateTime start_time_;
    public override DateTime StartTime
    {
        get
        { 
            return start_time_; 
        }
        internal set
        {
            start_time_ = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Optionally, use an interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this when deriving from a base class, but you can do it when implementing an interface.

So if you can replace your base class with an interface instead then it will work.